# Switching between Dark and Light Mode in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, styling

I'm using the [`useDarkMode`](https://github.com/donavon/use-dark-mode) library in React.

```
import useDarkMode from 'use-dark-mode'

const DarkModeToggle = () => {
    const darkMode = useDarkMode(false)
    return (
        <>
            {darkMode ? (
                <button type="button" onClick={darkMode.disable}>
                    ☀
                </button>
            ) : (
                <button type="button" onClick={darkMode.enable}>
                    ☾
                </button>
            )}

        </>
    )
}
```

I want the buttons to switch between the sun and moon, and be able to switch between dark mode and light mode. I can't seem to work out how to do this, I've also tried using hooks to with no luck.

Comment: Could you provide a source of the library

Comment: You might want to recheck this link https://usehooks.com/useDarkMode/

Comment: https://github.com/donavon/use-dark-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the documentation [`useDarkMode()`](https://github.com/donavon/use-dark-mode) returns an object with the properties like `value`:

> `value`: A boolean containing the current state of dark mode.

So most probably you can try with the following:

```
{darkMode.value ? (
   <button type="button" onClick={darkMode.disable}>
       ☀
   </button>
) : (
   <button type="button" onClick={darkMode.enable}>
       ☾
   </button>
)}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

If @norbitrial's answer turns out to be correct you may also have a way of shortening your code to improve its readability :

```
<button type='button' onClick={darkMode.value ? darkMode.disable : darkMode.enable}>
     {darkMode.value ? '☀' : '☾' }
</button>
```

Going even further :

```
const DarkModeToggle = () => {
    const { value, disable, enable } = useDarkMode(false)
    return (
        <button type='button' onClick={value ? disable : enable}>
            {value ? '☀' : '☾'}
        </button>
    )
}
```

The library also seems to offer a [`toggle` function](https://github.com/donavon/use-dark-mode#return-object), removing the need for `enable` or `disable`, now that you use the same button for both :

```
const DarkModeToggle = () => {
    const { value, toggle } = useDarkMode(false)
    return (
        <button type='button' onClick={toggle}>
            {value ? '☀' : '☾'}
        </button>
    )
}
```